# Transform resets(redraws) all my former moved views

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm moving around image views with timers and animation blocks. At the same time a user can click on a few of these views(buttons) and then I have some more animation blocks that start moving/resizing/rotating different image views.

Changing alpha of views and giving out new CGpoint to views works very well for me but calling resizing or rotating with the uiview.transform function seems to reset all my views to their starting position(from the storyboard).

I really would love to be able to use this transform function inside an animation block but if I can't somehow bypass this reset it is not really a viable option for me.

example code:

```
- (void)moveGust:(NSTimer*) timer
{
    if(centerCloud1.x >= 1100)
    {
        centerCloud1.x = -79;
        gustOutlet.center = centerCloud1;
    }
    if(centerCloud2.x >= 1100)
    {
        centerCloud2.x = -79;
        cloudOutlet.center = centerCloud2;
    }

    centerCloud1 = gustOutlet.center;
    centerCloud1.x = round(centerCloud1.x+10);
    centerCloud2 = cloudOutlet.center;
    centerCloud2.x = round(centerCloud2.x+8);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^(void){
        gustOutlet.center = centerCloud1;
        cloudOutlet.center = centerCloud2;
    }completion:^(BOOL Finished){ }];
}

- (IBAction)signAction:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^(void) {
        signTop.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(signTop.transform, 1.1, 1.1);
    }];
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Same thing happens when I add a subview to my screen. [self.view addSubview:_birdView]; ... basically I just want my 2 clouds not to go back to their first position when ever a view is transformed or a new view is added to the screen :(...

Answer (score 0):

Successive transforms need to be concatenated using CGAffineTransformConcat().

When you set the view's transform equal to a new transform, you effectively "undo" previous transforms.  To do a series of transforms, concatenate them with the above method.

Comment: Not really sure how I apply this since my transforms are all over the place and they are not on the same view at all(in the same view controller but they are all for different image view outlets). I'll take a look at this though and see if I can figure it out, thank you.

Comment: CGAffineTransformConcat() is only used to combine different transforms for a single view isn't it? I'm doing transforms on different views or just simply moving around a view and doing a transform on another view. The transform then resets my movement on the former view(which are inside the same ViewController on a StoryBoard)...